# Why is playback whisper-quiet on iPhone using NuGet package Plugin.AudioRecorder?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, avplayer, volume

Using the Plugin.AudioRecorder NuGet in Xamarin Forms / iOS, I am able to record audio on iPhone 8 but on playback it is whisper quiet. How to increase the sound volume?

In AppDelegate.cs I have:

```
AudioPlayer.RequestAVAudioSessionCategory (AVAudioSessionCategory.PlayAndRecord);
```

Comment: Terribly curious why the downvote. Should I have mentioned what was implicit, that the volume buttons were set to maximum? Not that downvotes bother me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default playback was via the phone's upper speaker. Directing output to the lower speaker solves the problem.

In AppDelegate.cs, add:

```
AudioPlayer.OnPrepareAudioSession = x =>
            {
                // Route audio to the lower speaker rather than the upper speaker so sound volume is not minimal
                x.OverrideOutputAudioPort ( AVAudioSessionPortOverride.Speaker, out NSError error );
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

AudioPlayer.OnPrepareAudioSession was not getting called for me. An alternative solution to direct audio output to the lower speaker:

```
var audioSession = AVAudioSession.SharedInstance();
var success = audioSession.SetCategory(AVAudioSession.CategoryPlayAndRecord, out var error);
if (success)
{
    success = audioSession.OverrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.Speaker, out error);
    if (success)
        audioSession.SetActive(true, out error);
}
```

I ran this code in my AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching() override